# Pojo values are not being retrieved correctly

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a ArrayList of POJOs that I populate from a result set retrieved from JDBC, when in the first `System.out.print` statement in the while loop, the data is retrieved perfectly using the getStatus method, however, when checking in the loop right after that one, the return value of getStatus is null.

P.S. status field is a String object with plain old getters and setters, nothing fancy.

```
while (result.next()) {
    POJO recordPojo = new POJO();
    recordPojo.setRefNo(result.getString(3));
    recordPojo.setSubmittedBy(result.getString(1));
    recordPojo.setCreatedDate(result.getDate(2).toString());
    recordPojo.setGuid(result.getString(4));
    recordPojo.setStatus(result.getString(5));
    System.out.println(" DBOPERATIONS  RESULT Ref No ----" + result.getString(3) + "      ===== " + result.getString(5) + " ====== " + recordPojo.getStatus());
    arryObj.add(recordPojo);
}
POJO x;
for (int k = 0; k < arryObj.size(); k++) {
    x = (POJO) arryObj.get(k);
    System.out.println(" DBOPERATIONS Ref No ----" + x.getRefNo() + "      ===== " + x.getSubject());
}
```

Comment: can you should us your inputs please? something weird in your code :(

Comment: Is there something already in your arryObj before you load it from the result set?  Also, your second loop isn't printing status, it's printing subject, which isn't set in your first loop.

Comment: Can you show us the complete code fragment? What's the type of the `result`?

Answer (score 3):

I consider this like a typo **(Subject is not Status)**, but I will give you a short explication: I think you are wrong in your Second `System.out.println()` of your loop `x.getSubject()`, you don't ever fill this field before with your result, so it's clear it is `null`.

So you have two options:

- fill this field when you loop your result
- Or print the correct field instead of `x.getSubject()`, you should to print the `x.getStatus()` (they are not the same)